# When we declare a vector<set<int>> r, we can easily insert elements into set by r[0].insert(10). Similarly, how is it done in java?

Tags: java, c++

I actually tried a lot to get this in java but when accessing the HashSet in the ArrayList of Hashsets(`List<HashSet<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>();`). for example, I have a 2D array and I want to insert each column element into ArrayList of HashSet. Like

```
vector<set<int>> cols(n);

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        cols[j].insert(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Now, how to convert the line `cols[j].insert(arr[i][j])` into Java?

Comment: Exactly the same way but with different names.

Comment: Recommendation: Show the Java version even if doesn't work. It shows us out here what you have tried, providing a good baseline for potential answers.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is the basic steps of porting a program form one language to another: 1) Understand the visible behaviour of the source program. 2) implement the visible behaviour of the source program in the new language, applying the new language's best practices and idioms. 3) Test the new program against the source program to ensure they have the same visible behaviour.

Comment: Note that the original code is only involved in step one and not in step two. More often than not if you directly translate any language to another you wind up with an inferior translation, if not [laughable nonsense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)